# How to end the sound that is being play?

Tags: sound

I'm trying to imitate the way that piano makes a sound and I create a DynamicModule to be the key like the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[Graphics[{col, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {0.5, 3}, {0.5, 5}, {0, 5}}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 
     Tiny]], {"MouseDown" :> {(col = 
       col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red}), 
     EmitSound[Play[(1 - t)*Sin[440 2 Pi t], {t, 0, 1}]]}},
  {"MouseUp" :> {(col = col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red})}}]]
```

Now it can change color when I press it and play the certain sound.
But I want to get it more realistic by starting to weaken the sound that is playing when I release my mouse.How can I do this? Or is there any other methods that can get similar result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SoundNote` that already sounds as piano (or other instrument) and on mouse up you can play any sound of duration `0` and volume `0` that stops the previous sound.

```
DynamicModule[{col = Green}, 
 EventHandler[
  Dynamic[Graphics[{col, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {0.5, 3}, {0.5, 5}, {0, 5}}]}, 
    ImageSize -> 
     Tiny]], {"MouseDown" :> {(col = 
       col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red}), 
     EmitSound[
      Sound[SoundNote[0], 5]]}}, {"MouseUp" :> {(col = 
       col /. {Red -> Green, Green -> Red}), 
     EmitSound[Sound[SoundNote[0], 0, SoundVolume -> 0]]}}]]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried the method just now but it didn't work as I want. I changed the volume and duration of the soundnote, finding that two sound were played at the same time.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Maybe the function `Play` is different with `Sound` in the `EmitSound`. It works when I use `Sound` both as you did.